# Update QSSL libraries in order to use OpenSSL 3.x

Tags: qt, ssl, openssl, qt6, qsslsocket

I've installed Qt 6.3 in Ubuntu 22.04 and I discovered this:

```
Incompatible version of OpenSSL (built with OpenSSL 1.x, runtime version is >= 3.x)
The backend "cert-only" does not support QSslKey
Active TLS backend does not support key creation
```

As far as I understand, that means,Qt 6.3 was built with the old OpenSSL 1.x, but my systems have the newer 3.x.
Because I can't wait the next fall for Qt 6.4 I ask if there is a workaround to fix this issue.

Is it possible to re-build only this module with OpenSSL 3.x and overwrite the libraries?
Any other suggestion?

Comment: That would mean rebuilding all of Qt with openSSL-3. openSSL-1 and -3 are not backwards/binary compatible, so you would have to modify your Qt to work with openSSL-3. It seems far more reasonable to just download and ship a working openSSL-1.1 binary with your application.

Comment: Yeah, you can, re-build Qt 6.3 with OpenSSL 3, you might have some errors about deprecated functions in OpenSSL3 but you can easily fix them, for example: `q_SSL_get_peer_certificate` -> `q_SSL_get1_peer_certificate`. It means, you also need to modify the source code of Qt 6.3 a little bit for the re-building.